# JavaFX + FXML integration with Spring

Tags: spring, javafx-8, fxml

I want to integrate javaFX with Spring IOC. For that I have found some valuable tutorial on [steveonjava.com](http://javafx.steveonjava.com/javafx-in-spring-day-2).

Can any one please tell me with that "ScreensConfiguration" (as display on below) class, how I am going to load some Controller with FXML.

That means currently  "ScreensConfiguration" class only load FXML + DialogBox related (depended) UIs know. I want to load some Controller UI with this manner.

Thanks a lot.

```
@Configuration
@Lazy
public class ScreensConfiguration {
    private Stage primaryStage;

    public void setPrimaryStage(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    }

    public void showScreen(Parent screen) {
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(screen, 800, 500));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @Bean
    CustomerDataScreen customerDataScreen() {
        return new CustomerDataScreen(customerDataScreenController());
    }

    @Bean
    CustomerDataScreenController customerDataScreenController() {
        return new CustomerDataScreenController(model, this);
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    AutowireFXMLDialog errorDialog() {
        return new AutowireFXMLDialog(getClass().getResource("Error.fxml"), primaryStage, StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    AutowireFXMLDialog addUserDialog() {
        return new AutowireFXMLDialog(getClass().getResource("AddUser.fxml"), primaryStage);
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    AutowireFXMLDialog loginDialog() {
        return new AutowireFXMLDialog(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml"), primaryStage, StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    }
}
```

Comment: you integrating for desktop app or for web?? JavaFX is used for most of the time for desktop app??

Comment: @Swing-Fx2GURU yes as you mention this is a desktop application. In later I have ingratiate spring data access also. Thanks.